# Kafka OffsetRequest current version

Tags: java, offset, kafka-consumer-api

In the following piece of code, what is the kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion() and what is the significance of that? Its not clear to me from the documentation available.
On what scenarios, a different version id is required?

```
OffsetRequest request = new OffsetRequest(requestInfo,
    kafka.api.OffsetRequest.CurrentVersion(), consumer.clientId());
```